# How to stop turtle freezing without using turtle.mainloop()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

When I am asking the user for an input to the turtle, the turtle page freezes. 
I have tried using `turtle.mainloop()` but that just stops the program altogether.
Is there a way I can prevent both the turtle page from freezing and the program from stopping?

Here's the code:

```
import turtle  
import time 
import random
def quickshape(sides,size,thickness):
    int(thickness)
    turtle.width(thickness)
    int(sides)
    int(size)
    angle = 360 / sides
    int(angle)
    for i in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(angle)
def correct_position():
    global x
    global y
    turtle.penup()
    x = random.randint(-400,400)
    y = random.randint(-250,250)
    turtle.setpos(x, y)
def move_alot():
    global x
    global y
    turtle.penup()
    x += random.randint(-100,100)
    y += random.randint(-100,100)
goes = 1
print("My Doodle .co can draw you lots of shapes, depending on what you ask us!")
print("To make a new set of patterns, close the pattern page... but only when it is drawing.")
print()
print("Before we start, do you want day or night mode?")
while True:
    mode = input("Mode: ")
    if mode == 'day' or mode[0] == 'd':
        print("Day mode it is.")
        mode = 'day'
        break
    elif mode == 'night' or mode[0] == 'n':
        print("Night mode it is.")
        mode = 'night'
        break
    else:
        print("Hmm... which mode?")
titlename = input("Title: ")
print("Configuring - takes a couple of seconds...")
while True:
    turtle.ht()
    turtle.tracer(0)
    turtle.screensize()
    turtle.setup(width = 1.0, height = 1.0)
    turtle.title(titlename + " [waiting for input - do not close]")
    print("[ pattern",goes,"]")
    while True:
            try:
                sides = int(input("Sides: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("[Input Error]")
            else:
                if sides > 35:
                    print("Warning: >35 sides")
                break
    try:
        turtle.penup()
        x = random.randint(-200,200)
        y = random.randint(-100,100)
        turtle.setpos(x, y)
        while True:
            try:
                numshapes = int(input("Amount: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("[Input Error]")
            else:
                break
        while True:
            try:
                size = int(input("Length of each side: "))
            except ValueError:
                    print("[Input Error]")
            else:
                break
        while True:
            try:
                thickness = int(input("Thickness: "))
            except ValueError:
                    print("[Input Error]")
            else:
                break
        if mode == 'day':
            if goes == 1:
                print("Setting up the day...")
            turtle.bgcolor("white")
        else:
            if goes == 1:
                print("Setting up the night...")
            turtle.bgcolor("black")
        print("We are now drawing...")
        turtle.width(thickness)
        part = 1
        int(part)
        for part in range(numshapes):
            turtle.penup()
            viewpart = part + 1
            int(viewpart)
            percentage = round(int(viewpart)/int(numshapes) * 100,2)
            turtle.title(titlename+" [drawing pattern. "+str(percentage)+"% complete.]")
            R = random.random()
            G = random.random()
            B = random.random()
            turtle.color(R, G, B)
            x += random.randint(-10,5)
            y += random.randint(-5,10)
            if int(turtle.xcor()) > 650 or int(turtle.xcor()) < -650 or int(turtle.ycor()) > 500 or int(turtle.ycor()) < -500:
                correct_position()
            else:
                if random.randint(1,45) == 1:
                    move_alot()
            turtle.forward(x) 
            turtle.left(y)
            turtle.pendown()
            quickshape(sides,size,thickness)
            turtle.update()
        print("Finished drawing pattern",goes)
        turtle.title(titlename + " [finished drawing pattern " + str(goes) + "]")       
    except turtle.Terminator:
        print("The page was closed when we were drawing.")
        print("Reseting number of patterns...")
        turtle.title(titlename + " [reseting...]")        
        goes = 0
        print()
    else:
        print()
    goes +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here's the code - but its not too important for the question.

The code is *always* important for the question!

There's sufficient code, and the issue is reasonably vague, that I'm going to try the approach of translating your code into Python ;-) , and have you see if your problem persists:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import random, randint

def quickshape(sides, size, thickness):
    turtle.width(thickness)
    angle = 360 / sides

    for _ in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(angle)

def correct_position():
    global x, y

    x = randint(-400, 400)
    y = randint(-250, 250)

def move_alot():
    global x, y

    x += randint(-100, 100)
    y += randint(-100, 100)

print("My Doodle .co can draw you lots of shapes, depending on what you ask us!")
print()
print("Before we start, do you want day or night mode?")

goes = 1

while True:
    mode = input("Mode: ")

    if mode[0].lower() == 'd':
        print("Day mode it is.")
        mode = 'day'
        break

    if mode[0].lower() == 'n':
        print("Night mode it is.")
        mode = 'night'
        break

    print("Hmm... which mode?")

titlename = input("Title: ")
print("Configuring - takes a couple of seconds...")

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)
screen.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)

if mode == 'day':
    screen.bgcolor("white")
else:
    screen.bgcolor("black")

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

while True:
    screen.title(titlename + " [Waiting for input - do not close]")
    pattern = "[Pattern {}]".format(goes)

    sides = screen.numinput(pattern, "Number of sides:", default=6, minval=3, maxval=35)

    if sides is None:
        break

    sides = int(sides)  # numinput() returns float

    numshapes = screen.numinput(pattern, "Number of shapes:", default=3, minval=1, maxval=50)

    if numshapes is None:
        break

    numshapes = int(numshapes)

    size = screen.numinput(pattern, "Length of each side:", default=25, minval=5, maxval=500)

    if size is None:
        break

    thickness = screen.numinput(pattern, "Thickness of pen:", default=1, minval=1, maxval=10)

    if thickness is None:
        break

    x = randint(-200, 200)
    y = randint(-100, 100)

    for part in range(1, numshapes + 1):
        turtle.penup()

        percentage = round(part/numshapes * 100, 2)
        screen.title(titlename + " [Drawing pattern. " + str(percentage) + "% complete.]")

        turtle.color(random(), random(), random())

        if randint(1, 45) == 1:
            move_alot()
        else:
            x += randint(-10, 5)
            y += randint(-5, 10)

        if not (-650 < x < 650 and -500 < y < 500):
            correct_position()

        turtle.setposition(x, y)
        turtle.pendown()

        quickshape(sides, size, thickness)

        screen.title(titlename + " [Finished drawing pattern " + str(goes) + "]")
        screen.update()

    goes += 1

screen.mainloop()
```

I've left out the feature:

> To make a new set of patterns, close the pattern page... but only when
> it is drawing.

as once you close the window, you *can't* get Python turtle started again.